# redux-auth-wrapper infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, authorization, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to integrate redux-auth-wrapper with https://github.com/mxstbr/react-boilerplate and I've failed on so many levels, but finally I'm getting close.

Right now I've managed to update the state whenever login is pressed, and my protected routes redirect to /login if the user isn't authorized. I've also managed to successfully redirect users to either index (if there is no redirect specified) or to a non-protected route if one is specified.

However, I'm getting into an infinite redirect loop whenever I login with redirect being set to a protected route. Here's a description of what happens.

1. I go to the protected route /foo.
2. I get redirected to /login?redirect=%2Ffoo
3. I login and state updates successfully.
4. I get redirected to /foo. (Presumably with a state.get('user').name not returning null)
5. I get redirected to /login?redirect=%2Ffoo
6. Go to step 4 aka repeat repeat repeat

So in essence, /login thinks I'm authorized and /foo thinks I'm not. I have tried changing my index route to protected and I'm getting the same error as with /foo.

Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Did you get any solution for this. I am also stuck in the same loop.

Comment: in your `foo` component, have you `mapStateToProps`? Is user mapped to that component? It could be that user is not passed as props in `foo` and on mounting it doesn't finds the user as null and therefore redirects.